# How to define a class reference in a Java class using Generics?

Tags: java, oop, generics

How to define the following class design using Java?

```
class Test
{
    private ClassA classA;
    **Placeholder for class reference**
}
```

In the above placeholder, either I want to pass instance of ClassB or ClassC. How to declare the variable?

```
class ClassB
{        
    List<ClassD> classDList;
}

class ClassC
{
    List<ClassE> classEList;
}

class ClassD
{
    String string;
    List<ClassE> classEList;
}

class ClassE
{
    String string;
    List<ValueObject> valueObjectList;
}
```

Please suggest me if there is any other better solution for the above design.

Comment: Make ClassCB and ClassDB extend ClassB?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If `ClassCB` and `ClassDB` have nothing in common, then why do you want to use them interchangeably?

Comment: Java doesn't have disjoint union types. So unless ClassB and ClassC have a common supertype (an interface?), you can't do that. But, many libraries have `Either<L,R>` type, so use could use that: `Either<ClassB, ClassC>`

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "as a common type", but: if `ClassCB` and `ClassDB` both *extend* `ClassB`, then instances of `ClassCB` or `ClassDB` are assignable to a variable of type `ClassB`.

```
class ClassB {}
class ClassCB extends ClassB {}
class ClassDB extends ClassB {}
```

It doesn't seem like generics has anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test<A,B>
{
    private A classA;
    // A common type for ClassCB and ClassDB
    private B classB;
}
```